# How does the woorank loader (css) works?

Tags: css, animation, loader, geometry

I tried to understand how does the WooRank loader (of rank) is working by the CSS?

Take a look on the below shot so you'll understand what im asking for.

[image]

While the background of the loader is

[image]

this is a wonderful animation that i wanna know how to do myself.

Answer (score 0):

It's not done with CSS. They use [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) to build an SVG. You can find the JavaScript code for the generation around line 844 in [their JavaScript file](http://www.woorank.com/assets/js/script-v2.js?8).

You might also look at [this example](http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html), it uses some similar effects.

I'm note sure if there is a practical solution in pure CSS right now. Anybode else got some ideas?